# How to add missing code dependencies on run time in .net and MVC5?

Tags: .net, dll, dependency-management, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 web application running on staging. I have functionality for which I want to export some of its views related models and controllers(dll) and some static content as a separate published bundles to the user so that user can host it to their IIS, make some changes in the _layout.cshtml or in the static contents and they can upload the changed content to my web application again.

The exporting part is fine but I am struggling in identifying the required code dependencies (third party dlls or other project dlls) which are required the published bundle to run. I don't want to export the full bin folder as it has many more dependencies and it would increase the exported bundle size too large. Is there a way or tool which I can use on a run time event (button_click action may be) which can help me identifying the required dependencies of the exported package so that I can add only those dlls within the bin of the exported package.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer, thanks for the guideline link=. If it is there, it should be followed by all the community user including me :). agreed.